# Jeremy Corbyn said ISIS supporters should not be prosecuted for 'expressing a political point of view'

Tags: united-kingdom, law, armed-conflict

I'm a bit baffled as to what Mr Corbyn really meant by [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/06/05/jeremy-corbyn-said-isil-supporters-should-not-prosecuted-expressing/):

> “I have no support for ISIS whatsoever, and obviously that
>   should apply to someone who has committed crimes, but we should bear
>   in mind that expressing a political point of view is not in itself an
>   offence"

[Expression](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expression) - "The action of making known one's thoughts or feelings"

So i assume if someone expressed support for ISIS and talked in the streets the law says its okay?

But one little snag. UK was at War with ISIS when the statement was made. Isn't it Treason to support ISIS even peacefully when at war with them? Aren't you an Enemy of the State at such instances?

I'm thinking back to WW2. When the UK went to war with the Nazis. was it a problem to do the same in the streets? i.e express support for the enemy or did they hang you up to dry for Treason?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60068/discussion-on-question-by-tasos-jeremy-corbyn-said-isis-supporters-should-not-be).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Has the UK issued a formal declaration of war against ISIS (which is not really a soverign nation)? No? Then the rules of conduct during full out warfare don't really apply. If the UK reacted to ISIS the way they reacted to Germany, they'd round up all the people that were from or had associations with areas under ISIS control, and intern them on the Isle of Man, like they did with German citizens in 1940. During WW2, all nations routinely interned citizens of hostile nations as a matter of practice.

I agree with Corbyn... contingent upon what one considers 'political expression'. Murdering innocent people is not political expression.

If ISIS has a political manifesto, it is the accumulation of as much power as possible. It is, after all, run by a group of brutal street thugs - the cherry picked pieces of Islam were adopted as a recruiting and motivational tool.

I can't imagine anyone expressing a genuine 'ISIS political opinion', and not looking like a complete fool in the process. So, by all means, don't outlaw discussing 'ISIS politics'. More people should have a good look at what that group is really all about.

Comment: Ok i get it. Not at War so the War rules dont apply to citizens but you can Intervene (The deliberate act of a nation or a group of nations to introduce its military forces into the course of an existing controversy) and have political views about it. The Law needs to change cause it sounds all technical to me. You drop bombs, the other side(s) declares war on you but youre not. -- ill check the specs of war -- good answer by the way

Comment: @Tasos You may want to read up on the related distinction between groups like the IRA (banned terrorist organisation) and Sinn Fein (legal political party currently campaigning for the elections tomorrow).

Comment: @origimbo -- ok thanks. as i said i was thinking WAR but the reality is INTERVENTION against ISIS. Hence the reason why INTERVENTION  can go on for 100 years no questions asked, keep the ball roling

Comment: @Tasos ISIS isnt a state its an organisation and proposes an ideology this nonsense that George Bush invented about a "War" isn't actually legally applicable. If you call the campaign against ISIS a war ... then technically speaking no one from ISIS has ever commited an act of terrorism because it will all be an act of "War" which is legally allowed

Comment: @SleepingGod -- War is a state of armed conflict between societies. A society is a group of people involved in persistent social interaction, or a large social group sharing the same geographical or social territory, typically subject to the same political authority and dominant cultural expectations.

Comment: The original question was on a legal point. When a nation enters a formal state of warfare with another nation, laws do change regarding freedom of speech and expression, to insure a maximum war effort. True of the UK, the US, and most democracies. Since the UK isn't in a formal state of warfare with ISIS, which is not a soverign nation, then those laws reserved for states of formal warfare are not applicable. Corbyn is right on that point. Saying nice things about ISIS, however misguided that may be, is not a treason offense, due to the absence of a formal declaration of warfare.